# How can I connect to Redis outside the cluster using Istio?

Tags: redis, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I installed Redis inside my Google Kubernetes Engine cluster using helm and it is working:

```
kubectl get svc -n redis-system

NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
redis-headless   ClusterIP   None          <none>        6379/TCP   99d
redis-master     ClusterIP   10.0.30.29    <none>        6379/TCP   99d
redis-slave      ClusterIP   10.0.31.102   <none>        6379/TCP   99d
```

I can connect to it using kubectl but now I want to use redis-cli in my local machine and connect directly to it. Then, I created a Gateway and a VirtualService using Istio:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: redis-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: redis-port
      protocol: TCP
    hosts:
    - redis-hm.myhost.com.br
----------------------------------------------------------------
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: redis-virtual-service
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - redis-hm.myhost.com.br
  gateways:
  - istio-system/redis-gateway
  tcp:
    - route:
      - destination:
          host: redis-master.redis-system.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 6379
```

When I use the following command it connects to the host:

```
redis-cli -h redis-hm.myhost.com.br -p 80 -a mypassword
```

But when I use the command **ping** it returns:

```
Error: Protocol error, got "H" as reply type byte
```

If possible I would like to solve this problem only using yml files to be applied using kubectl without editing anything in Istio. Thanks.

Comment: You connect in redis-cli and perform commands, the only one that is not working is ping, is it right? Please describe all steps and commands you are using.

Comment: All the commands that I use returns Error: Protocol error, got "H" as reply type byte

Comment: Hum, seems redis-server is not reachable. Try to use a port-forward to make sure redis-server is working,example: `kubectl port-forwared svc/redis-master 6379:6379` this will map the port 6379 to localhost. Try to connect using `redis-cli -h localhost -a mypassword`. Any special reason to use istio? Let me know if it works.

Comment: My cluster uses Istio and every request pass through Istio ingress-gateway. I already tried port-forward without success.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your case, but can't got the same issue. From where the host `redis-hm.myhost.com.br` resolves? Also, I've tried connect using portfoward and it works for me. I'm using GKE with istio enabled, redis deployed by helm. Could please share more details how to reproduce the same behaviour?